# xslt: how to remove comma of missing tag

Tags: json, xml, xslt

Hi i have made xslt which receive xml and output in json.
i am facing a problem which is if in xml last tag is not present it will add a comma and generate invalid json. so i need to remove that last comma.

my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Envelope">
{
    <xsl:if test="Enrollment">"Enrollment": 
    [
        <xsl:for-each select="Enrollment">
        {
            <xsl:if test="enrolleeRecords">
            <xsl:for-each select="enrolleeRecords">
            "enrolleeRecords":
            {

                <xsl:if test="employerId">"employerId": "<xsl:value-of select="employerId"/>",</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="legalName">"legalName": "<xsl:value-of select="legalName"/>",</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="enrolleeList">"enrolleeList":
                [
                    <xsl:for-each select="enrolleeList">
                    {
                        <xsl:if test="refId">"refId": "<xsl:value-of select="refId"/>",</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="enrolleeType">"enrolleeType": "<xsl:value-of select="enrolleeType"/>",</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="employeeId">"employeeId": "<xsl:value-of select="employeeId"/>",</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="personalInfo">
                            <xsl:for-each select="personalInfo">
                            "personalInfo":
                            {
                                <xsl:if test="firstName">"firstName": "<xsl:value-of select="firstName"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="middleName">"middleName": "<xsl:value-of select="middleName"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="lastName">"lastName": "<xsl:value-of select="lastName"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="birthDate">"birthDate": "<xsl:value-of select="birthDate"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="gender">"gender": "<xsl:value-of select="gender"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="maritalStatus">"maritalStatus": "<xsl:value-of select="maritalStatus"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="ssn">"ssn": "<xsl:value-of select="ssn"/>"</xsl:if>
                            },
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="contactDetails">
                        <xsl:for-each select="contactDetails">
                        "contactDetails":
                        {
                            <xsl:if test="enrolleeAddress">
                            <xsl:for-each select="enrolleeAddress">
                            "enrolleeAddress":
                            {
                                <xsl:if test="addressLine1">"addressLine1": "<xsl:value-of select="addressLine1"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="addressLine2">"addressLine2": "<xsl:value-of select="addressLine2"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="city">"city": "<xsl:value-of select="city"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="state">"state": "<xsl:value-of select="state"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="zip">"zip": "<xsl:value-of select="zip"/>",</xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="country">"country": "<xsl:value-of select="country"/>"</xsl:if>
                            }

                            </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="phoneNumber">"phoneNumber": "<xsl:value-of select="phoneNumber"/>",</xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="emailAddress">"emailAddress": "<xsl:value-of select="emailAddress"/>"</xsl:if>
                        },
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:if>
                    }
                    </xsl:for-each>
                ]</xsl:if>
            }
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        }
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() != last()">,</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    ]</xsl:if>
}
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() != last()">,</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

now the problem is if xml missing of tags ssn or country then json output become invalid. is there anyone who helps me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the comma into the following conditional so change

```
                ....  ,
  <xsl:if test="zip">"zip": "<xsl:value-of select="zip"/>",</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="country">"country": "<xsl:value-of select="country"/>"</xsl:if>
```

to

```
  <xsl:if test="zip">,"zip": "<xsl:value-of select="zip"/>"</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="country">,"country": "<xsl:value-of select="country"/>"</xsl:if>
```

Comment: but if both zip and country is missing then the condition will remain same

Comment: @salman I mean: move all comma into a similar test so you only add a comma if you are adding a following field.

Comment: @salman see edit: I've tried to make that clearer by showing the comma for both zip and country guarded by the corresponding xsl:if

Comment: i have made these changes as you suggested to all tags. but problem remains same when firstName in personalInfo tag is missing in my xml input then it adds extra comma at the start of the personal info........